# what could be causing a 60,000 ms delay on server

Tags: php, jquery, performance

I have created my website on vertrigo and everything was fine the load speed near enough instant but now i have uploaded it to my server but now i am getting

```
Location: United Kingdom
Error/Status Code: 200
Client Port: 3415
Start Offset: 0.784 s
DNS Lookup: 737 ms
Initial Connection: 43 ms
SSL Negotiation: 0 ms
Time to First Byte: 60347 ms
Content Download: 81 ms
Bytes In (downloaded): 7.8 KB
Bytes Out (uploaded): 0.3 KB
```

When i remove this and just upload a basic HTML file that outputs something it works almost instant.... could this be down to the .htaccess file?

i have

```
  RewriteRule    ^Home/([0-9]+)/?$        index.php?page=$1   [NC,L]
```

on all pages throughout the site, i have done speed check's and removed all the content like images, javascript from the file and the same happens - could this be the server or the website ?

Comment: Does the php code use any outside APIs?

Comment: Try to debug it with die('...') statements to figure out which line of code causes this delay. I bet the first line in the front index.php file will also have an instant response.

Comment: Check the script... it's processing something. Maybe it has a `sleep(60)` in it, or calls to an API, etc..

Comment: it calls the facebook api for share button/comments but i have removed these from the code - i will have a try with the die(). to see if it solves anything

Comment: thank you @OndřejMirtes.. Am getting somewhere with debugging with die()... dont know why i didn't think of that

Comment: @Maerlyn - that was the first things i removed & checked for slowing the code down

Comment: `Time to First Byte: 60347 ms` says that this is not a client-side problem. Removing images, scripts, and other resources will not matter. This is totally in php.

Answer (score 3):

[Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) has a performance profiler that will show the execution time at a function-level. So if one function is taking a long time, XDebug will show you exactly how much time that function took compared to everything else. I recommend installing this on your development environment, but don't bother in production. It will also help in tracking down lots of other problems.